# GWT plugin(java) rebuilt does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on Eclipse 3.7 with GWT 2.4.0.
I encountered a GWT compiler error, so downloaded GWT source code from

```
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

and fixed one source file, built it and replaced whole directory

```
plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0
```

Then I restarted eclipse and refreshed my project and executed GWT compiler, but it has no effect, still outputs the same error message as before. I checked for many times corresponding error logging line is completely deleted from the source file. I also tried local installation of whole plugin in vain.

What kind of mechanism prevents me from fixing source code of GWT plugin?

Comment: ...and the error message is?...

Answer (score 0):

What do you have selected for your SDK in Eclipse under *project -->properties -->google --> web toolkit*?

For example, I have two listings for gwt2.4, and when I select *Configure SDKs* I can see that I have more than one version in the *plugins* dir.

Perhaps eclipse is configured to use a different plugin dir than the one you have modified.

Comment: Of course I confirmed for many times that I am using newly replaced one(I don't know why it is automatically versioned as 0.0.0 instead of 2.4.0...). Thanks.

Comment: then I would remove all other versions and try again.  I had a similar issue where it was stuck on another SDK even though I requested another.  That was not my own build but it definitely refused to change the SDK until I deleted the other ones.

Comment: It seems to not work for my case. Is the plugin resistant to modification of its contents?

Comment: Building whole dist by 'ant dist-dev' resolved the problem. Thanks all.